# ContextMenu Click Event firing more than once

Tags: c#, contextmenu

This is really strange, for some reason my `contextmenu` clicks are firing more than once. I have the contextmenu tied to a button, so when the button is clicked the `contextmenu` is shown under it (with more options).

One option is to save `listview` to Excel, the other is to save to .csv.

So basically what happens here is that multiple excel sheets will open. Of course I only want one excel to open :)

Here is my code:

```
private void toolButtonNoBorder3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
contexMenuuu.Show(toolButtonNoBorder3, 
                                 new Point(0, toolButtonNoBorder3.Height));
contexMenuuu.ItemClicked += 
               new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(contexMenuuu_ItemClickedd);
}


void contexMenuuu_ItemClickedd(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
contexMenuuu.Hide();
contexMenuuu.Close();


if (e.ClickedItem.Text == "Excel")
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = 
                    new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    app.Visible = true;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet ws = 
           (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets[1];
    int i = 1;
    int i2 = 1;
    int iad = 1;
    foreach (ListViewItem lvi in flatListView1.Items)
    {
        i = 1;
        foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem lvs in lvi.SubItems)
        {
            if (i2 == 1)
            {
                iad = 1;
                foreach (ColumnHeader lvfi in flatListView1.Columns)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        ws.Cells[i2, iad] = lvfi.Text;
                    }

                    catch (Exception ee)
                    {

                    }

                    iad++;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    ws.Cells[i2, i] = lvs.Text;
                }

                catch (Exception ee)
                {

                }
            }


            i++;
        }
        i2++;
    }
}
else if (e.ClickedItem.Text == "CSV")
{
    Stream myStream;
    SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();

    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "csv files (*.csv)|*.csv";
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
    saveFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

    if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        if ((myStream = saveFileDialog1.OpenFile()) != null)
        {
            myStream.Close();
            ListViewToCSV(flatListView1, saveFileDialog1.FileName, true);

        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Yes, that happens when you subscribe the Click event more than once.  Like you do in your code.  Every time the user clicks the toolButtonNoBorder3 button, you add another event handler to the same Click event.  That code belongs in the constructor so it is only done once.

Comment: Quote: `That code belongs in the constructor`

Answer (score 4):

It should be in a constructor of your window:

```
public MyWindow()
{

//here inicialization

contexMenuuu.ItemClicked +=
new ToolStripItemClickedEventHandler(contexMenuuu_ItemClickedd);
}
```

This is a very common error to add event handler more than once, be careful next time

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have solved it using following statement -

`e.Handled = true;`

This will mark the event as handled (Obviously).